# How to get a shared drive change event(like drive renamed, addition or removal of a member, etc) using google drive webhook?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API v3 to fetch the google drive file. I have fetched shared drive metadata with files info. I have implemented Webhook to get notification about the changes in all files as well as changes related to the shared drive(like addition or removal of a member, drive renamed, etc.) As mentioned in this link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes#resource link the webhook response only contains the resource/item which has changed.
 It doesn't give a specific idea about what type of change has occurred. 
As per the google drive documentations, Google Drive keeps a change log for each user and shared drive. 
Can anybody give me an idea to get the specific event name(like member added or removed, drive renamed, etc.)? Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no way to see if someone has been removed from the file sharing. As you can see from the [list changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) method it returns a list of all of the changes to a file

```
{
  "kind": "drive#changeList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "newStartPageToken": string,
  "changes": [
    changes Resource
  ]
}
```

A [change resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes#resource) does not appear to contain any information about who the file was shared with

```
{
  "kind": "drive#change",
  "type": string,
  "changeType": string,
  "time": datetime,
  "removed": boolean,
  "fileId": string,
  "file": files Resource,
  "teamDriveId": string,
  "driveId": string,
  "teamDrive": teamdrives Resource,
  "drive": drives Resource
}
```

Unfortunatly the information that you have is going to be limited your might want to consider adding a feature request for sharing changed information you can do that [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I have gone through the list changes and change resources object. Google Drive provides the limited information about change.

Comment: I have one more Q. Can we get list of members of shared drive? I went through the Google Doc but didn't get any API.

Comment: you can get a list of files in a users shared drive and then scan through the list to see who else the files are shared with maybe thats just a guess

Comment: ok....It means it my Shared drive contains 50K files the I need fetch all files' permissionIds & then track added member...Right??

Comment: Yup its really the only way i can think of doing it.  Its going to eat a bit of your quota doing it though.